# Embedded elasticsearch test in java application

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I use Elasticsearch 7.11.2 with the following dependencies to write unit tests

```
    implementation 'org.codelibs.elasticsearch.module:lang-painless:7.10.2'
    implementation 'org.codelibs.elasticsearch.module:analysis-common:7.10.2'
```

Spinning up a node looks like

```
        public EmbeddedElastic() throws NodeValidationException, IOException {
        tempDir = Files.createTempDirectory("elastic_search_temp").toAbsolutePath().toString();

        int port = getAvailableBasePort();
        Map<String, String> settings = new HashMap<>();
        settings.put("path.home", tempDir);
        settings.put("http.port", Integer.toString(port));
        settings.put("transport.tcp.port", Integer.toString(port + 1));
        settings.put("transport.type", "netty4");
        settings.put("http.cors.enabled", Boolean.FALSE.toString());
        new PluginNode(settings).start();
        client = new RestHighLevelClient(RestClient.builder(new HttpHost("localhost", port, "http")));

        System.out.println("Client: " + client.getClass().getName());
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // file deletion
            }
        });
    }

    private static class PluginNode extends Node {
        public PluginNode(Map<String, String> preparedSettings) {
            super(InternalSettingsPreparer.prepareEnvironment(Settings.EMPTY, preparedSettings,
                                                              null, () -> "node-test"),
                  Lists.newArrayList(Netty4Plugin.class, ParentJoinPlugin.class, CommonAnalysisPlugin.class,
                                     PainlessPlugin.class),
                  false);
            System.out.println("Started local elastic with PainlessPlugin loaded.");
        }
    }
```

Now I am upgrading to ES 7.16.2 and the same code doesn't work well. I presume its because of the `lang-painless` and `analysis-common` libraries. Their latest version is only 7.10.

The exception I receive after upgrading the elasticsearch client to 7.16 and `spring-data-elasticsearch` to 4.3.0

```
Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchOperations]: Factory method 'elasticsearchTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/elasticsearch/common/xcontent/ToXContentObject
```

Before I dive deep into fixing it, I am wondering if anyone has actually made unit tests work with 7.16 ES version? I have seen that Elasticsearch Test containers is the recommended way to go

EDIT:

Thanks to Augusto's tip on checking classes in Maven Central, I found out that `lang-painless` depends on certain libraries from elasticsearch client which are not available in the higher versions of ES client. So its not possible to write unit tests with the same libs.

Answer (score 3):

Elasticsearch moved this class in 7.16 from the `org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent` package to the `org.elasticsearch.xcontent` package, a breaking change between 7.15 and 7.16.

Spring Data Elasticsearch 4.3 is built against 7.15.x and so won't work with Elasticsearch 7.16 libraries.

You either need to use Elasticsearch 7.15 or wait for Spring Data Elasticsearch 4.4 (the first milestone for that should be published next week) to be released which is built against 7.16.

And, yes, you should better use testcontainers.

Comment: The 4.4 version is still not available at https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/data/spring-data-elasticsearch/

Comment: Doesnt seem to be published here either https://repo.spring.io/ui/native/release/org/springframework/data/spring-data-elasticsearch

Comment: it's a milestone release, check https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch as how to get these

Answer (score 1):

You are probably missing the dependency with this class. It could be that before it came transitevily with the ES client.

Try adding `org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-x-content:7.15.2` to your build tool. A word of caution, you might be missing other dependencies too.

Just as a tip, if you ever get a NoClassDefFoundError, one of the easiest ways to find where that class is defined is to search in [maven central](https://search.maven.or). Search for `fc:<fully_qualified_class_name>`, and it will show all the jars where the class is present.

Comment: That's a great tip. Thank you! What's surprising is that I am pulling in ES client 7.16.2 and the class which is not found is present in `org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-x-content:7.15.2` and not in `org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-x-content:7.16.2` as per the maven central repo. I included both the versions one by one but still getting the `NoClassDefFoundError` for the same class.

Comment: To ensure that the lib is not pulled in by test plugins I added 
```    implementation ('org.codelibs.elasticsearch.module:lang-painless:7.10.2') {
        exclude group: 'org.elasticsearch', module:'elasticsearch-x-content'
    }
    implementation ('org.codelibs.elasticsearch.module:analysis-common:7.10.2') {
        exclude group: 'org.elasticsearch', module:'elasticsearch-x-content'
    }
```
but no luck